# Stop change between dropdown option using up and down key in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, primeng

I have made a dropdown options using primeng. Now if a user clicks on drop-down filed and press UP and Down key. So on pressing these key dropdown options should not be changed.

I have tried preventDefault() methond and stopPropogation() method. but still or key press I am bale to change the dropdown options.